# How to sum a hundred of raster maps in GRASS GIS raster calculator

Tags: grass-gis, raster-calculator, grass-7.0

I have 120 maps with the same name pattern: arc_01, arc_02, arc_03, arc_(...) and want to sum all of them in one.

Does anyone know how to do it automatically in GRASS GIS raster calculator?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Also, please do not double-post here and mailing list.

Answer (score 7):

You should consider using [`r.series`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass73/manuals/r.series.html). Perhaps something as follows will work in your case:

```
r.series input="`g.list pattern='arc_*' sep=,`" output=arc_sum method=sum
```